# How to pass ostream objects?

Tags: c++, cout, ofstream, ostream, ampersand

i have a struct like this

```
struct X{
    ostream out;
    X() : out(cout) {}
    ...
};
```

and I noticed that I have to define out with the & to correctly pass cout as default parameter: ostream &out; I don't know why and I don't know if there are other possibilities keeping ostream without the &. Furthermore, when I try to set

```
X x;
ofstream out;
x.out = out;
```

the compiler found many errors... I want to be able to set X::out to cout or to an ofstream. How to do it?

Comment: `ostream` is essentially an abstract base class, which moreover is not copyable (but movable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ostreams cannot be passed by value. You have to pass by reference or pointer.

If you want the ability to make `x.out` refer to different streams during its lifetime, then make it a pointer. Otherwise make it a reference.

Comment: I wonder why. One could implement copy and assignment semantics similar to a shared_ptr, couldn't one? I.e. all copies refer to the same fd and share one buffer, unless re-assigned to.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Well, you can always just do `std::shared_ptr<std::ostream>` (which has the same problems as a stream class doing this directly would have)

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can probably do is to change your class design so that you don't need to initialize a member variable anymore. Copying is prevented by the compiler, solutions based on pointers will introduce ownership issues, `std::shared_ptr` creates troubles with `std::cout`, and a reference member will create the possibility of dangling references.

Try to refactor your code such that a stream is always passed as a reference to methods from outside when needed:

```
struct X{
    X() {}
    void f(std::ostream &os);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Stream object are cannot be copied, you need to use reference.

```
struct X{
    ostream& out;

     X() :out( std::cout ) {}

     // X( ostream& out_ = std::cout ) : out( out_ ) {}

};
```